# CollaborationInvitation Object not visible while extracting in Dataloader

Tags: data-loader

Is the CollaborationInvitation object labelled with some different name. I am not able to see the object in Dataloader. 
I am able to see it in the query editor of Developer console. It is quite strange why it is restricted to dataloader. 
Any ideas ?

Comment: Even few more objects i am not able to see them

CollaborationInvitation
DatacloudAddress
EmailMessageRelation
LoginEvent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select Show all object. Then you can view this object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks I am able to see it now... Do you know the label name for DatacloudAddress
EmailMessageRelation
LoginEvent

Comment: @VishalNayak Unfortunately no. You need to manually traverse.

Comment: @VishalNayak You can write a quick Execute Anonymous script to see the value: `System.assert(false, SObjectType.CollaborationObject.getLabel());` (replace with the object you want the name for).